# How to calculate probability using R for particular event

Tags: r, statistics, probability

Consider I have this dataframe

```
Climb no.  No. of Climbers    Total people reaching Top   A is in climb
   1              7                     2                     Yes
   2              5                     3                     No
   3              10                    1                     Yes
```

How can I find using R the probability one particular person A will reach the top of the mountain for each climb?
Thanks for any direction

Comment: It looks like you don't have any data on person A, so how can you find the probability that person A will reach the top without more information or assumptions? Perhaps I am misunderstanding

Comment: Yes, I dont have data on A its randomly decided who reaches the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, the probability that any one person will reach the top is simply the number who reached the top divided by the total number of climbers (assuming that each person is equally likely to reach the top).

```
dat<-data.frame(Climb=c(1,2,3),Climbers=c(7,5,10),Top=c(2,3,1))

dat$Top/dat$Climbers
[1] 0.2857143 0.6000000 0.1000000
```